# Choice of Wind Instrument for self learning

Tags: flute, harmonica, soprano-recorder

I've been playing the piano (learning on my own) for over 2 years now and I would call myself above novice. I can't read sheet music but I have a good ear.

However, I was diagnosed with a problem and can't really play piano for long so I'd like to play a wind instrument, instead. Primarily: Recorder, Harmonica and Bamboo flute. I like all three and my disorder won't interfere with me playing any of these three.

My needs are:
something affordable, light and **something I can learn on my own.**

Ideally, I'd also like one or more of the following:

1. Not too difficult/Simple to pick up and play. No complicated techniques to learn.
2. Good online resources
3. Versatile

I mostly like covering the vocal parts of popular songs to play at parties etc. like Coldplay.

Comment: Might help to know what styles of music you're interested in. Penny whistle is cheap, and light, and there's a fair bit of music available online, but most of it is Irish...

Comment: Might be a little bit difficult and have a steep learning curve at first months but the clarinet is a good instrument. As you have good ears to pick up the song easily, after learning the basics of clarinet it may be more joyful for you than the other instruments recommended because it is adoptable to many genres of music from arabesque to classical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you enjoy classical, ethnic or folk music, go for the recorder. However, as you say you like rock, I'd say the harmonica is more common for this genre. Also, since you're playing at parties, I'd also choose the harmonica because it is louder than the recorder.

### Harmonica

1. It's simple, but like any instrument it gets more complicated as your learn more, but definitely an easy instrument to start on.
2. There are many good online resources for it.
3. Very versatile. It's used in many genres from jazz to blues and rock and even some classical.
4. Relatively cheap. You can get cheap versions, but like any other instrument, you can go as expensive as you wish.

### Recorder

1. It's simple to learn. However, it requires significant study to master.
2. There are more online resources for the recorder than the harmonica as it is frequently used in schools.
3. It's used for mostly classical and folk music. I've never heard someone stand up and play a rock song on a recorder.
4. One of the cheapest instruments there is. Of course, the professionals play on thousand dollar recorders, but you can get a decent recorder cheaply.

---

There's not a lot of difference in price between your basic harmonica and basic recorder. This is more of a non-issue. Although there are more online resources for the recorder, there are still plenty for the harmonica. This is another non-issue.

Considering your situation, I'd recommend the harmonica. It's easier to teach oneself, it's often used in the genres you want to play, and it's cheap.

Comment: Holy crap. I thought you were being hyperbolic when you said "thousand dollar recorders", but http://www.bellwoodviolin.com/recorders.shtml <- $1800!! Wow.

Comment: You can spend as much money as you want on anything.

Comment: Yes, of course, but that doesn't mean you're getting proportional value. Definitely makes you wonder.

Comment: I have been playing harmonica for a year now. And I can say it's definitely worth it! It's easy to start and fun to play. I prefer to play blues or folk, and man! It fits me perfectly. (It's my second instrument. The first one is guitar. And the other benefit is to use a harmonica along with guitar)

Comment: Just as a side note: I am actually playing the alto recorder in a folk/black metal band. That's not common, but not totally unheard of either :)

Answer (score 1):

After playing the violin for 15 years, I didn't have enough time to practice anymore. So, I switched to a woodwind instrument. I've been learning the Irish flute and Irish tin whistle on my own. It's very easy to start playing, especially if you're used to playing by ear.

The technique is really simple at the beginning and you can play a decent tune very quickly.

There are very good tutorials online (I'd start with [those tutorials](http://www.oaim.ie/free-lessons/whistle)), and you should also browse youtube videos as there are lots of tunes etc... [This website](http://www.thesession.org/) is also a very nice resource for finding new tunes.

The Irish flute and tin whistle are remarkably inexpensive.

You may not be able to play Coldplay with it though, but it's worth considering. A whistle can fit in your pocket if you want to play at a party.

Answer (score 0):

If your main points are affordable, light, and something you can learn on your own, I would go with bamboo flute. They are all affordable, however, the bamboo flute is easier to hold than a harmonica due to the hand position of the average harmonica. Choosing the bamboo flute over the recorder to me is because the bamboo flute has a much better sound. In my experience with recorders, they can squeak quite easily and have a less preferable sound compared to the bamboo flute. However, all three are great options and you will be happy no matter what you choose.